# Mapbox Shortest path for routing API

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-api-directions

For "driving-traffic" or "driving profile" i need to fetch shortest path from point A to B. Does "alternatives" option helps or am i missing something.

Comment: The Mapbox Directions API always returns duration and distance values but it will only return the shortest duration (fastest time) not the shortest distances. For instance, the trip may appear to be long in distance but actually faster because it favors high-speed roads.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed can use alternatives. There are more options to play with incl. Avoid highways.. no ferry ( might be shorter but higher cost (time schedule)
A route calculation gives back total time and distance, so play around with it!